# SQL Server - Triggers & Cursors - For Each Inserted Row, Update an Associated Value on Another Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For a homework assignment, I'm trying to build a trigger that allows for multiple inserts/updates/deletes by utilizing a cursor. **We have to use a cursor in order to practice the syntax**. We know that there are very few practical scenarios for cursors in a production environment.

**Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:**

For each row inserted into the TAL_ORDER_LINE table, update the ON_HAND value in the TAL_ITEM table by subtracting the NUM_ORDERED value from the stored ON_HAND value.

**Table Structure:**

[image: TAL Table Structure]

**Current Query:**

```
ALTER TRIGGER update_on_hand
ON TAL_ORDER_LINE
AFTER INSERT AS

DECLARE @vItemNum as char
DECLARE @vNumOrdered as int

DECLARE new_order CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ITEM_NUM, NUM_ORDERED
    FROM inserted

OPEN new_order;

FETCH NEXT FROM new_order INTO @vItemNum, @vNumOrdered;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    UPDATE TAL_ITEM
    SET ON_HAND = ON_HAND - @vNumOrdered
    WHERE ITEM_NUM = @vItemNum
FETCH NEXT FROM new_order INTO @vItemNum, @vNumOrdered;
END
CLOSE new_order
DEALLOCATE new_order
```

**My Insert Query:**

```
INSERT INTO TAL_ORDER_LINE (ORDER_NUM, ITEM_NUM, NUM_ORDERED, QUOTED_PRICE)
VALUES (51626, 'KL78', 10, 10.95), (51626, 'DR67', 10, 29.95)
```

It runs successfully, but does not affect the ON_HAND value. I think the biggest problem is that I'm struggling to understand cursor syntax, especially the INTO clause in the FETCH statement and how data from the 'inserted' table is passed into the cursor. What do I need to know to get this to work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a general rule: Avoid  cursors in triggers.

Comment: unless the assignment ask for it :)

Comment: Real-life advice: triggers should be kept **very nimble** and should **NOT** do any heavy calculations or processing - and they should ***most definitely*** avoid cursors at all costs! These are terrible performance killers and will bring down your system performance quite drastically..... ***DON'T DO THIS*** in the real world - ***EVER*** !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely due to this:

```
DECLARE @vItemNum as char
```

it is HIGHLY unlikely that the ItemNum column is a single character. For future reference, you should always verify that you variable definitions are consistent with the values you expect to store in them. And as has been hinted - you will get better answers by posting a complete script rather than a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Big question,how you gonna debug ?

Is On_Hand col NULL , then do this isnull(on_Hand,0)

```
DECLARE @vItemNum as char
DECLARE @vNumOrdered as int

DECLARE new_order CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ITEM_NUM, NUM_ORDERED
    FROM  TAL_ORDER_LINE

OPEN new_order;

FETCH NEXT FROM new_order INTO @vItemNum, @vNumOrdered;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    --UPDATE TAL_ITEM
    --SET ON_HAND = ON_HAND - @vNumOrdered
    --WHERE ITEM_NUM = @vItemNum
    print @vItemNum
    print vNumOrdered
FETCH NEXT FROM new_order INTO @vItemNum, @vNumOrdered;
END
CLOSE new_order
DEALLOCATE new_order
```

Comment: I'm not worried at all about debugging because this is a hypothetical database with no client interface, server-side logic, or reporting service. All I need to do is create a trigger that utilizes a cursor-based solution so that multiple rows can be inserted and updated. I thought my scenario would be much easier to accomplish, but it seems to be very challenging after all.

Comment: no,i meant how you test your script ?so my sctipt help you in testing the cursor.instead of inserted i use table name.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you were suggesting. If I would have printed those variables, I would have seen that my vItemNum variable should have been set as char(4), not just char. I assumed char covered any amount of characters. Thank you, it will help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ALTER TRIGGER update_on_hand ON TAL_ORDER_LINE
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE TI
    SET TI.ON_HAND = TI.ON_HAND - I.NUM_ORDERED
    TAL_ITEM TI INNER JOIN 
    INSERTED I ON I.ITEM_NUM = TI.ITEM_NUM


END
```

1. Changed Trigger to **FOR INSERT** Trigger
2. Removed Cursor

Note: **NOT Tested.** ( If you post the sql scripts for create table + sample inserts I can give it a try )

Comment: Sorry, the assignment requires a cursor be used just for the sake of practicing the syntax. We were taught that there are very few practical uses for cursors because in almost every circumstance a standard query can accomplish the same result. I'll edit my post so that everyone knows this.

Comment: If you want to tinker around, I could post the table creation scripts, but I populated my tables from the master tables on our server. Is there some way in SSMS to export table records as insert statements?